# Concatenar letras/palavras se contiver "&" e houver espaço entre elas

Tags: php

Como concatenar letras/palavras se contiver "&" e houver espaço entre elas?

Exemplo:

```
A & E COMERCIO DE ALGUMA COISA LTDA
EMPRESA P & C CONSTRUCAO LTDA
CAMARAO & CIA FULANO DE TAL - ME

// OUTPUT
A&E COMERCIO DE ALGUMA COISA LTDA
EMPRESA P&C CONSTRUCAO LTDA
CAMARAO&CIA FULANO DE TAL - ME
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode usar `preg_replace` para substituir a ocorrência de  `&` .

```
preg_replace("/ *& */", "&", $string);
```

Com essa regex vai substituir os espaços que existam antes e depois do &.

> * : indica que o parametro anterior ocorre nenhuma ou várias vezes.
>
> Neste caso, temos que pode existir: AS& DFG, AS & DFG, AS &DFG, AS&DFG, em todos estes casos ele vai dar match e executar o replace.

Exemplo:

```
$example = "A   &   E COMERCIO DE ALGUMA COISA LTDA";
$out = preg_replace("/ *& */", "&", $example);
echo $out; // A&E COMERCIO DE ALGUMA COISA LTDA
```

Manual do [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Boa @LuisHenrique, cara como ficaria se fosse o seguinte `CAMARAO &CIA FULANO-ME` ou `CAMARAO& CIA FULANO-ME` com espaços apenas de alguns dos lados?

Comment: Você pode usar `preg_replace("/ ?& ?/", "&", $example);`. O `?` faz match em 0 ou 1 ocorrência, enquanto o `+` em 1 ou mais. Outra opção é substituir o `?` por `*`, que quer dizer 0 ou mais ocorrencias.

Comment: @smigol atualizei a resposta considerando o caso de um dos lados já estar concatenado.

Comment: brigado @LuisHenrique

Answer (score 0):

Não entendo de PHP, mas tente isso ai:

A`\040`&`\040`E COMERCIO DE ALGUMA COISA LTDA
EMPRESA P & C CONSTRUCAO LTDA

**ou**

A`\s`&`\s`E COMERCIO DE ALGUMA COISA LTDA
EMPRESA P & C CONSTRUCAO LTDA